# Magento Custom Order Export CSV Data

Tags: magento, csv, orders

I'm trying to create a custom order export csv with lots of extra columns in my Magento install.

Here's an example CSV with the fields I need in the order export CSV:
http://philowen.co/sample/SampleWebOrderLines.xlsx

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/forum/viewthread/264960/

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is

Fall back the Grid.php file (app/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php)

then add your custom column like i did below:

```
//New columns added but hidded

$this->addColumn('custom_column', array(
   'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Column'),
   'index' => 'custom_column',
   'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
   'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
));
```

if you want to show this column in sales order grid just ignore these lines

```
   'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
   'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
```

also made change in

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('custom_column'));     
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

this means we have to add our custom column value to collection. For that we have to join our table with grid collection table.

Now go and check backend, export the orders.
there will be our custom column added.

Answer (score 1):

Its dated, but Inchoo has a good tutorial to get you started on Magento custom module development, and it luckily it walks you through the "export csv" functionality of the adminhtml:

http://inchoo.net/magento/tracing-magento-from-export-csv-to-save-file-ok-button/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using some of the modules that have that functionality

like this one
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-export-orders-to-csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try below extension.I hoe this should solve your purpose.
http://ext4mage.com/export-orders-to-csv.html

This is a free extension

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses. Eventually, I installed the Xtento Order Export plugin and it's amazing.

I had to create a new XSL template from scratch but managed to get everything working, including Sales Tax and Delivery Charges on their own lines.